# How do i make a discord bot check in what servers are you?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm working on a discord check bot (in python).
The bot should be able to see in what servers is a person since there is a permission when authorizing to allow that.
When used with the command "chk!check(memberName)", the bot should respond with something like this:

```
Servers that (memberName) is in:
Server1
Server2
Server3
Server4
```

Now, I have done most of the job like setting up the bot, the command, and the prefix.
I am not sure how to make the bot "read" the servers that the checked person is.
Any help? Thanks!

Also, the code I made so far is below

```
import discord
from discord.exr import commands

client = commands.bot(command_prefix = "chk!")


client = discord.Client()

@client.command()
async def check(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    await hereiswhereigotstuck

@client.event
async def on_ready:
    print('Bot Succesfully Started.')
    



client.run('token')
```

Comment: Did you try looking for `discord.Member` in the documentation, to see what functionality it offers? Maybe ctrl-f around there for anything to do with servers?

Comment: I am not convinced that there is a Discord API permission/ability to see what servers a user is in. The closest you could do is query if a user is in a server (guild) you are already aware of, all the guilds your bot is in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "obvious" answer would be to use [Profile.mutual_guilds](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=profile#discord.Profile.mutual_guilds), however Bot accounts are not allowed to access user profiles.

The only way for a bot to do this isn't terribly efficient, but you can iterate over all the guilds your bot is in with `client.guilds`, and then use something like [Guild.get_member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_member#discord.Guild.get_member) to check if the user is in that guild.

You could also see if your user is in [guild.members](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.members), but if your guild is massive I'm not sure how much more efficient this would be.